# How to solve vertica connection/vpn issue on sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-sagemaker, vertica

I am uploading my jupyter notebook code to sagemaker. In the code, vertica python connection failed. I got the error message:
Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address.

The code looks like this:

```
# load data
conn_info = {'host': xxxx,
             'port': xxxx,
             'user': xxxx,
             'password': xxxx,
             'database': xxxx,
             'schema': xxxx}

connection = vertica_python.connect(**conn_info)

cur = connection.cursor()
```

Comment: "Failed to establish a connection to the primary server or any backup address" means that you can't establish a connection, from the computer you are running your Jupyter notebook on, to the host you specify above under 'host': xxxx . Open a command line window, and go "ping xxxx"; if you see "destination host unreachable", my assumption is correct.

Comment: I have no problem running the code on the laptop when I vpn to pass the company firewall. But whenever I disconnect vpn or run the code on sagemaker(even when I on vpn), I get the error message.

Comment: Is there a way to get pass the firewall on sagemaker?